# Apollo-graphql: using withFilter

Tags: node.js, apollo, graphql-subscriptions

could you, please explain the origin of *variables* param passed to the `withFilter` function. An example provided [here](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-subscriptions#filters) does not explain it.

A `payload` is provided when `publish` is called, but `variables`...

From where do we get them? and if they are needed to be set, then how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured it out. `variables` are variables that are passed to a subscription.

For instance, if a subscription looks like this:

```
followUser(userId: String!): SomeType!
```

Then `userId` will be in `variables`